# How is the Gould Belt younger than the sun?

Tags: solar-system, time

Our sun is located in the [Gould Belt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gould_Belt), a  group of stars which is thought to be 30 - 50 million years old. However, the sun formed 4.6 billion years ago.

Did the belt form around us?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything is in motion in our Galaxy. The Sun has executed some 20 laps of the Galaxy since it was born and may have migrated inwards or outwards to some extent. The Sun's location has nothing to do with the Gould belt or vice versa.

The Gould belt stars formed just 30 million years or so ago. The position of the Sun relative to the Gould belt is a coincidence and it will not be in the Gould belt in another 30 million years or so, because it has motion relative to it.